# SELinux error while installing Awesome WM packages

Tags: fedora, selinux, awesome

After installing Awesome wm packages:

- awesome.x86_64
- rancid.x86_64
- vicious.noarch

I'm getting an error in SELinux Troubleshooter:

```
   The source process: useradd
Attempted this access: create
    On this directory: rancid

If you want to allow useradd to have create access on the rancid directory
Then you need to change the label on rancid
Do
# semanage fcontext -a -t FILE_TYPE 'rancid'
where FILE_TYPE is one of the following: alsa_home_t, antivirus_home_t, audio_home_t,
auth_home_t, cache_home_t, chrome_sandbox_home_t, config_home_t, cvs_home_t,
data_home_t, dbus_home_t, fetchmail_home_t, gconf_home_t, git_user_content_t,
gkeyringd_gnome_home_t, gnome_home_t, gpg_secret_t, gstreamer_home_t, home_bin_t,
home_cert_t, httpd_user_content_t, httpd_user_htaccess_t, httpd_user_ra_content_t,
httpd_user_rw_content_t, httpd_user_script_exec_t, icc_data_home_t, iceauth_home_t,
irc_home_t, irc_tmp_t, irssi_home_t, kismet_home_t, krb5_home_t, krb5kdc_var_lib_t,
local_login_home_t, mail_home_rw_t, mail_home_t, mail_spool_t, mandb_home_t,
mozilla_home_t, mpd_home_t, mpd_user_data_t, mplayer_home_t, mysqld_home_t,
openshift_cgroup_read_tmp_t, openshift_cron_tmp_t, openshift_rw_file_t, openshift_tmp_t,
openshift_var_lib_t, polipo_cache_home_t, polipo_config_home_t, procmail_home_t,
pulseaudio_home_t, rlogind_home_t, rssh_ro_t, rssh_rw_t, sandbox_file_t, screen_home_t,
selinux_config_t, selinux_login_config_t, semanage_store_t, semanage_tmp_t, smsd_var_lib_t,
spamc_home_t, speech-dispatcher_home_t, ssh_home_t, stapserver_var_lib_t, svirt_home_t,
systemd_home_t, telepathy_cache_home_t, telepathy_data_home_t,
telepathy_gabble_cache_home_t, telepathy_logger_cache_home_t,
telepathy_logger_data_home_t, telepathy_mission_control_cache_home_t,
telepathy_mission_control_data_home_t, telepathy_mission_control_home_t,
telepathy_sunshine_home_t, texlive_home_t, thumb_home_t, tvtime_home_t, uml_ro_t,
uml_rw_t, user_fonts_cache_t, user_fonts_config_t, user_fonts_t, user_home_dir_t,
user_home_t, user_tmp_t, useradd_var_run_t, var_lib_t, virt_content_t, virt_home_t,
vmware_conf_t, vmware_file_t, wine_home_t, wireshark_home_t, xauth_home_t, xdm_home_t. 

Then execute: 
restorecon -v 'rancid'
```

So I guess the question is, which of these should I run the command:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t FILE_TYPE 'rancid'
```

on to change the label?

Comment: The `rancid` package does not appear to be related to Awesome WM. It's for automatic backup of router config. Are you sure it belongs in this list?

Comment: oh, you're right. I thought it was for awesome when I did the search. I was obviously mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Rancid does not have anything to do with awesome. But in case anyone has a similar problem, it was the *useradd_var_run_t* option that did the trick. So the command was:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t useradd_var_run_t 'rancid'
```